# Configure apt to ignore a package's minor updates

Tags: ubuntu, apt

For some `apt` packages I don't want minor updates.

Is it possible to configure apt to ignore minor updates for a specific package, and not prompt me about such versions even when updating its database (`apt update`).

UPDATE
(Is this technically possible given that apt packages do not need to follow semantic versioning?)

Comment: Apt ... follows semantic versioning, for itself. Whether some random package uses semantic versioning is of course for that package's maintainers to decide and not for apt to dictate.

Comment: @muru Thanks I've update the question to make that clear. My point was if a package doesn't follow semver, I'm unsure whether I can tell apt to skip minors because apt doesn't know what is a minor for that package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn’t possible to determine the importance of a package upgrade based only on its version number. Consider, for example, [the latest FriBiDi security fixes](https://ubuntu.com/security/notices/USN-5366-1): the package version in 20.04 went from 1.0.8-2 to 1.0.8-2ubuntu0.1.

You *might* be able to get part of the way there by considering *repositories*. The “canonical” (pun intended) Ubuntu repositories on released versions of the distribution only receive important updates, so you can be confident that any package upgrade in those repositories should be applied. Any other repository can then be pinned so that the packages it provides are not considered as upgrades, with a pin priority strictly between 0 and 100; see [`man apt_preferences`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man5/apt_preferences.5.html).

If you want to filter versions on top of that, you can add a pin-priority on specific versions; for example, you could pin a package so that version 7.2.*x* is not an upgrade candidate, but anything else is — so once you’re on, say, 7.2.0, you won’t see upgrade candidates until the package bumps to 7.3.*x* or later:

```
Explanation: Skip 7.2.x patch releases as upgrades
Package: foo
Pin: version 7.2.*
Pin-Priority: 1
```